# Apple's PencilKit Demo not able to deploy to iPad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pencilkit

I want to install the demo code of Apple's PencilKit and run it on my iPad:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/drawing_with_pencilkit

I use:

- xcode 11.0
- iPad Pro with 13.1

I can deploy it to the iOS simulators but not to the iPad. I keep getting the error:

```
The app ID "<bundle-id>" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
```

Which fields must be changed such that it works. All the other solutions did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after system reboot ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

`Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.`

This field is in the "General" tab of you app's target.